# How can I add @@rowcount to this SQL query

Tags: html, sql, sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures

```
SET @tableHTML =
N'<H1>Report Heading</H1>' +
N'<table border="1">' +
N'<th>Check Number</th>' +
N'<th>Last Operator Date</th>' +
N'<th>Last Timestamp</th>' +
N'<th>Run Date</th>' +
N'<th>Issued Check Number</th>' +
N'<th>Error Description</th>' +
'<tr>' +
CAST ( ( SELECT td = S.CHK_NUM,       '',
                td = S.LAST_OPER_ID, '',
                td = S.LAST_TIMESTMP, '',
                td = S.RUN_DT, '',
                td = ISNULL(S.RE_ISSUE_CHK_NUM,-1), '',
                td = ISNULL(S.ERR_DESC,'<null>'), ''
          FROM STAGNG_CDDP_ERR_RCD S
          FOR XML PATH('tr'), TYPE 
) AS NVARCHAR(MAX) ) +
N'</table>' ;

PRINT @tableHTML
```

I want to count the resulting rows and assign it to a variable. How can that be achieved?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just add a count query:

```
DECLARE @tableHTML NVARCHAR(MAX), @Count int;

SELECT @tableHTML =
    N'<H1>Report Heading</H1>' +
    N'<table border="1">' +
    N'<th>Check Number</th>' +
    N'<th>Last Operator Date</th>' +
    N'<th>Last Timestamp</th>' +
    N'<th>Run Date</th>' +
    N'<th>Issued Check Number</th>' +
    N'<th>Error Description</th>' +
    '<tr>' +
    CAST ( ( SELECT td = S.CHK_NUM,       '',
                    td = S.LAST_OPER_ID, '',
                    td = S.LAST_TIMESTMP, '',
                    td = S.RUN_DT, '',
                    td = ISNULL(S.RE_ISSUE_CHK_NUM,-1), '',
                    td = ISNULL(S.ERR_DESC,'<null>'), ''
              FROM STAGNG_CDDP_ERR_RCD S
              FOR XML PATH('tr'), TYPE 
    ) AS NVARCHAR(MAX) ) +
    N'</table>'
    , @Count = (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM STAGNG_CDDP_ERR_RCD);

PRINT @Count;
PRINT @tableHTML;
```